# How to sort (custom) strings from a list

Tags: c++

I'm using a list structure that contains only strings. I have to sort them by length && alphabetically.

example input:

> tea, tram, top, ter, troop, true

results in:

> tea, ter, top, tram, true, troop

I can sort the strings on the number of characters, but I'm stuck on how to re-reorder alphabetically. The result string shows: tea,top,ter.. and they're not ordered alphabetically.
I'm using insertion sort and a auxiliary list.

```
List_pointer<string> odd1(odd);
auto p1 = odd1.next(odd1.begin());
auto p2 = p1;
if (!odd1.empty())
{
    while (!odd1.end(p1))
    {
        p2 = odd1.previous(p1);
    while (p1 != odd1.begin() && ((odd1.read(p2).size()) > (odd1.read(p1).size())))
    {
    {
        auto temp = odd1.read(p1);
        odd1.write(odd1.read(p2),p1);
        odd1.write(temp,p2);
    }
        p1 = odd1.previous(p1);
        p2 = odd1.previous(p1);
    }
    p1 = odd1.next(p1);
   }
}
cout << odd1 << endl;
```

I know that the error is here: `while (p1 != odd1.begin() && ((odd1.read(p2).size()) > (odd1.read(p1).size())))` but I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you have to implement it by hand? Or could you use `std::list`, too?

Comment: yes, I've built the list by myself.

Comment: I see that, my question was whether you can switch to `std::list`, which has a member function `std::list::sort` which does what you want. But you homework might also require you to not use the standard library, in which case this solution isn't doable.

Comment: is `string` an `std::string` ? this question is not reproducible

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce** it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use mine, I know that std::list has a lot of useful functions.

Comment: yes, string is std::string.

Comment: `std::string` has a compare function, which is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). If you only have english words, you could convert everything to lowercase (`std::tolower`) and use the compare function, which than should be alphabetical.

Comment: Try `std::sort(lst.begin(), lst.end())` where `lst` is the `std::list` you want to sort.

Comment: What's a `List_pointer`? is it `decltype(odd)::iterator`?

Answer (score 1):

The compare function to use is something like

```
bool compare_size_then_alpha(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
    }
    return lhs < rhs; // lexical order 
}
```